# Subqueries and a sequence of aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: teams and players. Players play in teams.

teams:

```
team_id  team_name  region
1        Spain      Asia
```

players:

```
team_id  player_id  age
1        1          27
```

I need to figure out from which region is the youngest team. So stepwise I need to find out the average age in each team, then the minimum of those values and then select the region with that minimum.

I wrote a query and it works only if the calculated minimum average is unique:

```
select teams.id, region, avg(age) as average from teams
inner join players_stat on teams.id=players_stat.id
group by teams.id, region
order by average asc
limit 1
```

But I don't know how to write a concise query if I have the same minimum age for more than one teams from the different regions. I tried to use up to 3 subqueries but haven't found an efficient way. What's most frustrating is that the following code gives me the desired minimum age

```
select min(a.average) from
    (select teams.id, region, avg(age) as average from teams
    inner join players_stat on teams.id=players_stat.id
    group by teams.id, region
    order by average asc) a
```

But I cannot get region information. If I include 'region' right after select, it then requires to include it in the 'group by' clause. If I do so it then calculates minimum by regions.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not include the region information until after you have calculated the minimum `avg(age)`.  To maintain all teams in case of a tie, use the `rank()` function.

```
with team_avg as (
  select team_id, avg(age) as avg_age,
         rank() over (order by avg(age)) as team_rank
    from players
   group by team_id
)
select t.*, a.avg_age
  from teams t
       join team_avg a
         on a.team_id = t.team_id
 where a.team_rank = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have a look at this rank() function.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query seems fine.  I would write it using table aliases:

```
select t.id, t.region, avg(ps.age) as average
from teams t join
     players_stat ps
     on t.id = ps.id
group by t.id, t.region
order by average asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have two teams from different regions with average age "32", for example, I can't put 'limit 1'